# Android Bluetooth scanning results available even when bluetooth is off

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

```
    BluetoothAdapter bluetooth = null;

    private BluetoothLeScanner scanner;

private ScanCallback scanCallback;


private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback;

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 18) {
                    BluetoothManager bluetoothMan = (BluetoothManager) context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
                    bluetooth = bluetoothMan.getAdapter();
                } else {
                    bluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                }


                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
                            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
                            btDevices.add(new BluetoothDeviceModel(result.getDevice().getName(), result.getDevice().getAddress(), result.getRssi()));
                            timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        }
                    };
                }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                    leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLeScan(BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                            btDevices.add(new BluetoothDeviceModel(device.getName(), device.getAddress(), rssi));
                            timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        }
                    };
                }


    if (!allPermissionsGranted(applicationContext, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS)) {
                return false;
            }
            try {
                if (!applicationContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                    return false;
                }



                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    if (permissionGranted(applicationContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
                        scanner = bluetooth.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                        scanner.startScan(scanCallback);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2){
                    bluetooth.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
                    return true;
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return false;
```

So what happens if I test this code in Samsung phone with Marshmallow, it works fine and does not throw any exception even when blueooth is off, instead it returns the bluetooth scanning results in the ScanCallback. 
But when I test it with Moto with android N and Lava with android Lollipop, it throws a NullPointerException when bluetooth is off.

Problem is when I am trying to get BluetoothLeScanner in this statement :

```
scanner = bluetooth.getBluetoothLeScanner();
```

Here, the method getBluetoothLeScanner is returning null when bluetooth is off. 
Can anybody tell me how it is happening?

Comment: Don't worry about these kind of corner cases. Just make sure bluetooth is enabled (and location as well) before starting the scan

Comment: Thanks Tim, But I was just wondering how can it be possible? Is it related to OS customization by vendor?

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth API on Android will return the known BT devices, so if you've paired with a device before, it'll show up on the results as well.

I believe that, like Tim said, you're facing a corner case, and you should really check whether or not the Bluetooth is turned on to avoid problems in the future.

Comment: Thanks Mauker, I will check it once again.